# How can I return the message "this is empty" from a function when the input is an empty array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, if-statement

I've written a function in javascript for finding the shortest string within an array. I want the function to return empty array when the input is an empty array. How can I do that ? Here is my code:

```
function tinyFriend(array) {
    var tiny = array[0];
  
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
      if (array[i].length < tiny.length) {
         tiny = array[i];
      } 
    }
    
    return tiny;
}
```

Comment: Inside the function check if array.length === 0 return [];

Comment: actually this function is for returning the shortest string from an array. What I want is when I give an empty array as input it should return an empty array. What condition should I set for that?

Comment: I just answered it @FIDAH

Comment: What research have you done to find out how to determine if an array is empty? See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: You've got two similar answers as I'm writing this.  Both copied your for loop, which, since you're setting tiny to array[0], should start with 1: `for(var i=1; i<array.length; i++) {`.

Comment: Note: those answers will return THE FIRST shortest string.

Comment: @iAmOren , I updated the answer , thank you for pointing out. Also you are right , it will return the first shortest element only if the there are multiple elements having same length . I only focused on what was asked in the question rather than optimizing the code.

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi, It will return the shortest, therefore the first shortest = even if there is only one = it's still the first... :)   Also, I use `var` even in `for` loops.  And, yes, I understand you answered according to question, that's why I've commented here and not in your answer - to show asker that there might be somethings overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

Check at start of the function is the length of array is 0 , return array else find the shortest element and return it

```js
function tinyFriend(array) {

  if(array.length===0)
    return array;
  else{
     var tiny = array[0];
  
    for (i = 1; i < array.length; i++) { 
      if (array[i].length < tiny.length) {
         tiny = array[i];
      } 
    }
    
    return tiny;
   }
}

console.log(tinyFriend(["test","testing","tester"]))
console.log(tinyFriend([]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this(note that you don't need `else` after `return []`:

```js
function tinyFriend(array) {
  if (array.length === 0) {
    return []
  }

  var tiny = array[0];

  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].length < tiny.length) {
      tiny = array[i];
    }
  }

  return tiny;
}

console.log(tinyFriend(['aa', 'bbb', 'c', 'dddd']))
```

Using ES6:

```js
const shortTinyFriend = array => 
  array.length > 0
   ? array.sort((a,b) => a.length - b.length)[0]
   : []

console.log(shortTinyFriend(['aa', 'bbb', 'c', 'dddd']))
console.log(shortTinyFriend([]))
```

Comment: In the "non-ES6" you can also give array a default value (of empty).

Comment: @iAmOren You mean `return tiny || []` ? Yes, but then all function body code would be executed even when `array.length` equal `0`.

Comment: No.  I mean: `function tinyFriend(array=[]) {`

Comment: @iAmOren Why not, but default parameters is an ES6 feature and it won't affect the returned value.

Comment: Thanks!  I did not know that.

Answer (score 0):

you should check at the beginning of function wheather input array is empty or not, something like this:

```
if (array.length ===0 ) {
    return array; 
    }
    else {
     for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].length < tiny.length) {
        tiny = array[i];
      } 
  }
 return tiny; 
 }
}
```